# Copying A SINGLE SELECTED row from a datagridview to another datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

what i need to do :
 1. When a user clicks on A ROW of a datagriview. Only this row is displayed in another datagridview (so that it can be edited etc...)

NOTE : grid_display = from where i need to get the row.
NOTE : grid_detail = to where i need the single row to be copied.

what i have till now:

```
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in grid_display.Columns)
            {
                grid_detail.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }

            //then you can copy the rows values one by one (working on the selectedrows collection)
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in grid_display.SelectedRows)
            {
                int index = grid_detail.Rows.Add(r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
                foreach (DataGridViewCell o in r.Cells)
                {
                    grid_detail.Rows[index].Cells[o.ColumnIndex].Value = o.Value;
                }
            }

            }
```

I am only able to make a new row. But not to feed in the selected row in it.
Any help ?

Comment: Read about `DataGridViewRow.Clone()` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone.aspx as it says `The Clone method copies the row and its property values, but does not copy the cell values that the row contains.` Usually you will manipulate the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` as its meant to be a View. So use a `DataTable` for each `DataGridView.DataSource` and copy rows from one table to another.

Comment: :) Mike u may chk the answer i posted. I was not looking for an easy ride. Just looking fr an easier way to do it :)

Comment: Anoushka, I know this can be done like this. But your approach is bad practise. You should understand, and use, the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`. My Answer boils down to the usage of `DataTable.ImportRow` and `DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt()`. These two functions are even more concise than your own answer. You should always use what the framework already contains instead of creating your own functions that do the same. The thing is that you are overwhelmed by the copy&paste example I gave you... Thats sad...

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment already, you should use a `DataSource` for your `DataGridView`s and use a `DataGridView` as view only.

Here you have complete example that demonstrates how to use a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` for a `DataGridView` and move a `DataRow` between them.

1. Creata a new windows forms project and copy paste the code.
2. Click on a row, by clicking left from the row (indicated with a small arrow > ) in the `DataGridView`
3. Click on the `Button` below the `DataGridView` to move the selected `DataRow` to the other `DataGridView`

NOTE 1: All the controls are crated in Form1_Load so dont bother drag dropping controls on the form.

NOTE 2: If you have only a column selected, no rows will be moved. You have to select the entire row.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load +=Form1_Load;
        }

        public DataGridView ViewA, ViewB;

        public DataTable DataA, DataB;

        public Button MoveSelectedFromViewAToB, MoveSelectedFromViewBToA;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create two DataGridViews on the form
            ViewA = new DataGridView()
            {
                Location = new Point(0, 0),
                Size = new Size(300, 100),
                MultiSelect = false
            };

            ViewB = new DataGridView()
            {
                Location = new Point(300, 0),
                Size = new Size(300, 100),
                MultiSelect = false
            };
            this.Controls.Add(ViewA);
            this.Controls.Add(ViewB);

            //Add Two buttons
            Button MoveSelectedFromViewAToB = new Button()
            {
                Text = "A => B",
                Location = new Point(10, 120),
            };
            MoveSelectedFromViewAToB.Click += MoveSelectedFromViewAToB_Click;
            MoveSelectedFromViewBToA = new Button()
            {
                Text = "A <= B",
                Location = new Point(310, 120)
            };
            MoveSelectedFromViewBToA.Click += MoveSelectedFromViewBToA_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(MoveSelectedFromViewAToB);
            this.Controls.Add(MoveSelectedFromViewBToA);

            //Make sure the form has appropriate size
            this.Size = new Size(600, 200);

            //Create a DataTable and add some data
            DataA = new DataTable();
            DataA.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(System.String));
            DataA.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(System.String));
            DataA.Rows.Add(new object[] { "KeyA", "ValueA" });
            DataA.Rows.Add(new object[] { "KeyB", "ValueB" });
            DataA.Rows.Add(new object[] { "KeyC", "ValueC" });
            DataA.Rows.Add(new object[] { "KeyD", "ValueD" });

            //Make sure DataB has the same layout as DataA
            DataB = DataA.Clone();

            //Assign both datatables to the views
            ViewA.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = DataA };
            ViewB.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = DataB };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Moves rows from view A to B
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void MoveSelectedFromViewAToB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewA.SelectedRows.Count == 0 || DataA.Rows.Count == 0 || ViewA.SelectedRows[0].Index > DataA.Rows.Count -1) return;//No row selected, or data table is empty
            DataB.ImportRow(DataA.Rows[ViewA.SelectedRows[0].Index]);
            DataA.Rows.RemoveAt(ViewA.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Moves rows from view B to A
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void MoveSelectedFromViewBToA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewB.SelectedRows.Count == 0 || DataB.Rows.Count == 0 || ViewB.SelectedRows[0].Index > DataB.Rows.Count -1) return; //No row selected, or data table is empty
            DataA.ImportRow(DataB.Rows[ViewB.SelectedRows[0].Index]);
            DataB.Rows.RemoveAt(ViewB.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        }
    }
}
```

With this you should be able to implement your logic of when to move a row to your `grid_detail` and when to move it back to `grid_display`.

Comment: Mike thank u fr ur attempt ... I still havent solved my problem, i may be not getting z points you are trying to point out to me.

Can you get me something more simple (i am new)

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn If you want to use a `DataGridView` things are not going to be more simple than the example I gave you. I strongly encourage you to interpret the code and analyze what is going on. I sense you are seeking for an easy ride, but thats not going to happen if you do not understand what a `DataGridView` is for and how to use it. Your approach of manipulting data in a `DataGridView` without a `DataSource` is bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i got to solve the problem.
I proceeded as below.

First i cloned the columns, for this i created a method

```
  public void change_header()
        {
            DisplayDataGrid();
            grid_detail.Columns.Clear();

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in grid_display.Columns)
            {
                grid_detail.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }
        }
```

then I copied the SELECTED row only and displayed it in the second datagridview (as header columns have already been duplicated) the data now displayed are presentable.

How I copied selected row ?
Here it is.

```
 grid_detail.Rows.Clear(); 
            DataRow[] dRows = new DataRow[grid_display.SelectedRows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < grid_display.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
                dRows[i] = ((DataRowView)grid_display.SelectedRows[i].DataBoundItem).Row;
                foreach (DataRow dgvRow in dRows)
                {
                    grid_detail.Rows.Insert(0, dgvRow.ItemArray);
                }
                grid_detail.Refresh();
```

Where grid_display is dgv with FULL data
and grid_detail is the dgv with the selected row only.
Thanks.

Comment: You are creating functionality that is already contained in the framework itself. Bad practise. Use `ImportRow` or a `DataTable` instead, and set the `DataTable` as the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score -1):

If the data your grid_display comes from a query (like MySQL, etc.), what you can do is to redo the query but make it specific so that the resulting data is the same as the one you selected when you clicked the cell from grid_display...then put the result in your grid_detail.

This is one solution I think you could do...but you cannot do multiple transfer at once because you are making a query...

Hope it helps... :D